How to send a request for eth to a user that they can confirm with their metamask wallet?
I am trying to build a Dapp that relies on this functionality.
A user will request another user for some eth, and the sender would then see a pop up notification on their wallet ex Metamask or some other and then confirm the transactionan after which the eth would be transferred?

this is what I have
provider.getTransactionCount(walletA.address)
.then((nonce) => {
const txRequest = {
to: walletB,
value: 0,
nonce: nonce,
data: ethers.hexlify(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(send ${ethers.formatEther(amountToRequest)} ETH)),
gasLimit: 50000,
};
return walletA.sendTransaction(txRequest);

})
.then(async (tx) => {
const resolvedTx = await ethers.resolveProperties(tx);

const receipt = await tx.wait();

})
.catch((error) => {
console.error('Error sending request:', error);
});

Here is outline

Create the request data and store it in a database
Create a web page that displays this request
Send a link of this web page to the user
When the user arrives to the web page, they can connect their wallet (there are many wallets, and although MetaMask is oldest, you need to support all wallets)
The web page then opens MetaMask the Send transaction request and the user can confirm, this is done using a library like Viem and JSON-RPC request which web page and wallet use to communicate

